# Access private methods in js/three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to write a three.js plugin but I need access to some private methods in WebGLRenderer, like addBuffer(), setProgram() and so on. Is there any way I can access them?

Comment: I guess we should make those methods public?

Comment: @mrdoob That'd be nice. I could work on the plugin and create a pull request with the changes that were necessary to WebGLRenderer. But maybe you've got another idea how to approach this. Basicaly, what I'm trying to do is to add one or two new Object types. PointCloud and PointCloudOctree. The first behaves very similar to ParticleSystem but it won't render easily because the renderer does instance checking. That's why I'm trying to render them with a PostPlugin.The second is different, in that it has not one geometry but an array of geometries that may change depending on the point of view.

Comment: @mrdoob I'm doing this because I want to see if I can integrate my point cloud renderer, potree, into three.js. See http://potree.org/demo/pompei/pompei.html

Comment: Sounds good! Hmmm... maybe it would be better to handle this on github issues?

Comment: I created one just now: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4726